# ¿por qué no entra el 0 en un arreglo de carácter? en C

Tags: c

Compilado con gcc (tdm64-1) 5.1.0, Windows 10

Estaba programando y me tope con un problema quiero añadir un 0 a un arreglo lo intente de la forma:

```
char *arreglo = (char *)calloc(0,sizeof(char)); 
Forma 1:
arreglo[0] = 0;
Forma 2:
arreglo = agregar(arreglo,0);
Forma 3:
char cero = '\0';
arreglo[0] = cero;
```

y las salidas no me arrojan nada se que el 0 es considerado como carácter nulo,
¿hay alguna forma de ingresar un 0 en el arreglo?

```
char *agregar(char *arr,int numero){
    arr[strlen(arr)] = numero;
    return arr;
}
```

hice varias pruebas y ninguna funciono ejemplo :

```
arreglo[0] = 0;
arreglo = agregar(arreglo, 2);
arreglo = agregar(arreglo, 0);
```

Salida:

```
2
```

que debo hacer para que la salida sea : 0 2 0, sin que el arreglo sea de tipo **int *arreglo** o poner el 0 como caracter la idea es ingresarlo a la lista como entero para poder trabajarlo, atoi("0") no funciona igual arroja el mismo resultado.

Comment: El cero si entra. Puedes agregar un cero al arreglo y funciona. Es sólo que cuando miras el arreglo como un string, el cero marca su fin (por convención). Por otra parte, el cero no tiene representación gráfica, entonces ¿por qué necesitas ponerlo dentro de un string?

Comment: Hola @Trauma Si funciona el agregar, el 0 no entra, ya que con una funcion que muestre el arreglo no muetra nada y al poner strlen(arreglo) marca 0 y en el caso del  0 2 0 y llamas strlen(arreglo) = 1, solo por el 2

Comment: @CandidMoe Lo necesito y que retorno la posición de un arreglo como inicio fin, entre otras cosas que retorno, entonces necesito ese 0 para poder trabajarlo, y si entiendo que el mecanismo de strlen y en base de string terminan en **'\0' ** queria saber si se encontraba un mecanismo, Truma, Gracias por la ayuda, al parecer no se puede

Comment: Oh buenisima lo intentare, gracias @CandidMoe lo probare

Comment: Ingresa el caracter '0'

Comment: Ese codigo esta mal. El primer parametro de la funcion calloc indica la cantidad de elementos a reservar y le has pasado un 0. Ahi hay un sintoma de comportamiento indefinido. Si quieres crear un array de caracteres y dejar un espacio para el caracter nulo, seria asi: `calloc((10 + 1), sizeof(char))`..

Comment: @MrDave1999 Muchas gracias